# Determine limit of given function

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the function $f(x) = 3x^2-x+3$.

Determine the $$\lim_{z \to x} \frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z - x}$$

I can't figure out a way to do it without getting 0, so if anyone could help me understand how to solve this that would be great.

Comment: That limit you are talking about is the derivative of the function at x

Comment: You must find a way to factorize the nominator!

Comment: @Carstairs since you are varying $z$ in the limit then the function must be written as $f(z)=3z^2 -z+3$, also ues I think that the limit is the derivative so the answer of the limit will be $6z-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(z) -f(x) = (3z^2)-z+3 -[(3x^2)-x+3] = 3(z^2 - x^2)-(z-x)$$

$$= (z-x)[3(z+x)-1]$$

Upon dividing by $(z-x)$ you get $3z+3x -1$

Now let $z$ approaches $x$ and see what is the result.